# How to make a UIButton/CollectionViewCell that changes with time Swift 3 programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create an object in my UICollectionView that changes based on a timer. For this example, we'll say the timer is one minute long. When the object in my UICollectionView is pressed, I want the animation inside the cell/button to begin. Here are a few images so you can get a sense of what I want it to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlR82.jpg

What type of object should I make it? How would I go about creating the animation?

Answer (score 0):

in your cellForItemAtIndexPath method

```
cell.buttonOutletName.tag = indexPath.row
cell.buttonOutletName.addTarget(target : self , selector : #selector(animateButton(_:)))
```

then create a function and perform animations

```
func animateButton(_ sender : UIButton){
//perform animations to the View 
}
```

I used indexPath.row to keep trace of what row was tapped